# Salesforce Marketing Cloud inApp (in-app) reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush, analytics

is there a way to report on in-app (inApp) messaging from Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Salesforce official answer to this questions is, that there is currently no way, except using the Journey Builder Analytics for the corresponding activity.

Does anyone know anything else?

Data View?
Data Extract?
Reporting?
Script?

I researched, but couldnt find anything.
Thank you so much.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the new Intelligence Reports there is a section with in-app message analytics, it's quite extensive and allows multiple ways to filter. You can also create a Report there and schedule it for export to a csv to an FTP or Cloud storage provider in case you need to report on the data in some other platform.
[image]

In the old Reports there is also a report you can use: Push In-App Account Summary Report